# In a scatter plot when a feature is plotted against itself, then it is not a straight line

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

[click to see the scatter plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ucoVq.jpg)

Here in the scatterplot of the iris dataset, we have for example sepal_length plotted against sepal_length then if they are the same value why isn't the graph a linear curve.

Comment: As stated in the [documentation](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.pairplot.html): _The diagonal plots are treated differently: a univariate distribution plot is drawn to show the marginal distribution of the data in each column._

Answer (score 1):

In your image, there is no scatterplot between `sepal_length` and `sepal_length`. In `sns.pairplot`, if it is the same feature on both axes of the scatter plot, it defaults to a histogram instead. That is what you are seeing.